# C++ reference collections

Tags: c++

So... you can't do an array of references but can you build a collection that will handle references, pointers, and values?

```
Collection<Integer32*> a;
Collection<Integer32&> b;
Collection<Integer32> c;
```

Here's the problem I'm running into:

```
template <class ItemType> class Collection
{
    public:
        Collection(ItemType array[]);  // or ItemType*, doesnt matter

    protected:
        ItemType* innerArray;
};
```

Compiler says nope no pointers to references...  Possible?

Comment: Does c++ have a concept of pointers?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am not a real c++ coder. but I have heard of only references(&) in cpp and never a pointer(*). atleast i dont know.

Comment: Lol well thanks for trying to help Sibi...

Comment: @Sibi ok then, yes, C++ has pointers, but references are to be preferred.

Comment: If collections can't support references then I'm not sure they are preferrable...

Comment: @RyanBrown in this case, smart pointers are to be preferred. References should be preferred when passing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Nope - `Collection<Integer32&> b;` isn't valid, you can't have a collection of references.

The rest though is legal - your class should compile.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just tried it out after your comment - http://ideone.com/cbAeN7 - this what you mean?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: huh, I didn't realize `list` and `set` couldn't hold references.  Well, I learned something today.  I should see if the container I'm making can hold references.

Comment: to store elements in container, the element must be copiable or constructable

Comment: @MooingDuck that'd be interesting to see.

Comment: @billz: Actually, the standard containers no longer require objects to be copiable, merely movable.  (Apperently move-assign is still required though, though I thought that was also optional).  I think they should alter the node based containers to make move-assignment optional like copy-assignment.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that `std::allocator<T>` requires `T*` to be valid, which isn't the case for `T&`, so the problem is less the container and more the allocator.

Comment: While attempting to make a allocator that could handle it, I discovered that I can't placement new a reference.  Who knew that was illegal?

Answer (score 1):

The standard containers like plain arrays don't support references as value types, but if you create your own collection type you can do this.

Internally a Collection will have to store the references as something that can be copied and assigned. You can use plain pointers or look at std::reference_wrapper for such a representation.

You'll probably need to use partial specialization for the reference case.